# how to move(or don't move) turtles just in special ways or patches in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

Imagine a city with streets that people move around the city and streets. How can i say to the turtles that move just in a certain ways or don't move in some ways(patches)?

Answer (score 1):

Some relevant models in the Code Examples section of the Models Library that I suggest you look at and study:

- **Look Ahead Example**: turtles look ahead of them before moving so they don't step on blue patches
- **Wall Following Example**: turtles treat brown patches as "walls", walking alongside them

In Look Ahead Example, the crucial snippet of turtle code is:

```
ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue
  [ lt random-float 360 ]   ;; We see a blue patch in front of us. Turn a random amount.
  [ fd 1 ]                  ;; Otherwise, it is safe to move forward.
```

In Wall Following Example, the behavior of the turtles is more complicated, so the code is a more complicated, too.

Comment: I want too add some walls and forbidden ways to flocking sample in models library in biology folder that birds can not fly on that special patches. How can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried using the code from Look Ahead Example yet? That seems like a good start to me.

Comment: yes. I tried Look Ahead Example. That was good. but when i want to add ti to flocking model i face to problems